# Matrix Rotation-counter clock wise

Tags: matrix

How can i rotate an MXN matric counter clock wise as per the image i ve attached.[image: the image shows the counter clock wise rotation of 4x5 martix once.]

Comment: yeah!! got it  , thanks for the info!!

Comment: the solution How do you rotate a two dimensional array?  is for matrix of size N*N.I want to know the solution for matrix of size M*N